# CSS Menu not working in IE8

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8

Please can someone help. Ive checked through all the topics and i cannot see what is wrong with my code:

This is the menu below, all the CSS.

Ive also changed the header to reflect a previous post i found which did not fix.

```
/* =Menu
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

#access {
background: #240E04; /* Show a solid color for older browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#471B07, #0C0401);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#471B07, #0C0401);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#471B07), to(#0C0401));  /* older webkit syntax */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#471B07, #0C0401);
font-family: TradeGothicCondensedNo18;
clear: both;
display: block;
float: left;
margin-left: 10px;
width:97.5%;
}
#access ul {
font-size: 18px;
text-transform: uppercase;
list-style: none;
margin: 0 0 0 0em;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-top: -50px;
}
#access li {
float: left;
position: relative;
}
#access a {
color: #eee;
display: block;
line-height: 2em;
padding: 0 0.8em;
text-decoration: none;
}
#access ul ul {
-moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
display: none;
float: left;
margin: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 2em;
left: 0;
width: 220px;
z-index: 99999;
}
#access ul ul ul {
left: 100%;
top: 0;
}
#access ul ul a {
background: #170802;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #ddd;
color: #fff;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: normal;
height: auto;
line-height: 1.4em;
padding: 5px 5px;
width: 350px;
border: solid;
border-width: thin;
border-color: #170802;
 }
#access li:hover > a,
#access ul ul :hover > a,
#access a:focus {
background: #7A330E;
}
#access li:hover > a,
#access a:focus {
background: #f9f9f9; /* Show a solid color for older browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#7A330E, #170802);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#7A330E, #170802);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#7A330E), to(#170802)); /* Older webkit syntax */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#7A330E, #170802);
color: #ffffff;
 }
#access ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}
#access .current-menu-item > a,
#access .current-menu-ancestor > a,
#access .current_page_item > a,
#access .current_page_ancestor > a {
font-weight: bold;
}

#footer {
background-color: #000000;
width: 97.5%;
height: 20px;
float: left;
clear: both;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: -0px;
font-family: 'Arial';
line-height: normal; 
font-size: 11px;
text-align: center;
color: #ffffff;
padding-top: 0.5%;
}
```

Comment: try at mozilla, sometimes IE not support.

Comment: create jsfiddle or post html code

Comment: Hi Rohit,What code? As i have posted the CSS up there, which i believe may have something to do with it, also i amended the <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">....

Comment: And nunu, it works fine on firefox, its just i want it to work cross browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI now change to your `html code`

`nav` tag change to `div`

as like this

Change into

```
    <nav role="navigation" id="access">
// here some code of your html
</nav>
```

**This**

```
    <div role="navigation" id="access">
// here some code of your html
</div>
```

because this `nav` tag is not support your `ie8` because you are using `HTML 4.0` this tag is Support `HTML5`

Comment: Removing HTML5 tags and recurring to DIV's is not a correct solution. There is a way to make IE8 and older support HTML5 tags, read my post.

Answer (score 1):

DON'T change your `nav` to `div`.
The problem is that IE8 and older don't allow you to style HTML5 tags.

Use the HTML5Shiv to make IE<9 support HTML5 tags.

http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

And include this tag:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

From wikipedia:

> HTML5Shiv is a JavaScript workaround, discovered by Sjoerd Visscher,
>   to enable styling of HTML5 elements in versions of Internet Explorer
>   prior to version 9, which do not allow unknown elements to be styled
>   without JavaScript.

Edit:
Also, since you're using HTML5 tags, you should change your DOCTYPE to:

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 0):

> nav tag is not support in ie8 and below version

you have to replace nav tag with div tag

**Like**

```
<nav>
Your Menu code here ...
</nav>
```

Hope it will work